# Why are the terminal color brighter than the ones I set?

Tags: terminal, color

I've changed my terminal's color but, as always, the color I set are rendered brighter than they really are.

Here's the proof, I set the exact same color on ST and on my term, you can clearly see the term is brighter.

[image]

Any clue why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the color profile to the profile used by your display before specifying the values:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the foreground behave as it should, the background needs to be explicitly declared with LSCOLOR (gnu) or LS_COLOR (linux).

The trick is to use the same color both for your ANSI palette background color and in your Terminal window non-ANSI setup.

I don't know why, but it works.